# How to limit height of animation (direction top)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to limit max height of animation when using arrows to switch. Trying to write a function, that will calculat height of div and +- step in px. But it's now writed to variable.

```
var maxfloorh = $('.floor-switch').height();
var actualh = $('.floor-switch').height();
$('.floor-switch li').click(function() {
    $('#line').animate({
        top: $(this).position().top
    });
});
function floorarrs(numbr) {
    switch (numbr) {
        case 1:
            //check here maxfloorh
            $('#line').animate({
                top: '-=18'
            }, 400, function() {
                maxfloorh-'18';
                console.log(maxfloorh);
            });

        break
        case 2:
              //check here maxfloorh
            $('#line').animate({
                top: '+=18'
            }, 400, function() {
                maxfloorh+'18';
                console.log(maxfloorh);
            });

        break
    }
}
$('.arrw-up').click(function() {
    floorarrs(1);
});
$('.arrw-dwn').click(function() {
    floorarrs(2);
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="floors" style="margin:60px;">
    <div class="arrw-up"></div>
    <div class="floor-switch">
        <div id='line'></div>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="arrw-dwn"></div>
</div>​
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/cxvec/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.arrw-up').click(function() {
  if ($("#line").css("top") !== "0px") {
    floorarrs(1);
  }
});

$('.arrw-dwn').click(function() {
  if ($("#line").css("top") !== ""+($("#pagination li").length-1)*18+"px") {
    floorarrs(2);
  }
});​
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxvec/3/)

I have changed the logic in your arrow `click` function, In css the initial `top` attribute of the element with `id=line` is set to `0px`
...Now whenever the `top = 0px` -> the div is on 1st `li` hence the function is not executed ans so for the down arrow...
**Note:** This may note be the best solution but it's one of the solutions